# R subset columns within a list

Tags: r, list, sorting

I have many data frame, so I import them as a list but I found that the number of columns of those data frames are different, so I decide I cut them off and I want to sort only columns 1 to 3 in all the data frames within the list.

```
list
[1]
TBBA-06-5415-01A-01D-1481-05    g01023169   0.956810536587318   BSL 7
TBBA-06-5415-01A-01D-1481-05    g03242877   0.0365834311749085  BSL 7
TBBA-06-5415-01A-01D-1481-05    g06008330   0.0400302305964602  BSL 7
TBBA-06-5415-01A-01D-1481-05    g08861569   0.0556296569207048  BSL 7
TBBA-06-5415-01A-01D-1481-05    g09748749   0.183017407923698   BSL 7
[2]
TBBA-62-A472-01A-11D-A24I-05    g02726808   0.860054268107413   OTB
TBBA-62-A472-01A-11D-A24I-05    g04243127   0.897393495417269   OTB
TBBA-62-A472-01A-11D-A24I-05    g10537079   0.875143441641266   OTB
TBBA-62-A472-01A-11D-A24I-05    g12497728   0.935925242951832   OTB
TBBA-62-A472-01A-11D-A24I-05    g13195463   NA  OTB
[3]
TBBA-KK-A7AV-01A-11D-A32C-05    g02442630   0.862838460053133   AS  9   133318907
TBBA-KK-A7AV-01A-11D-A32C-05    g11045524   0.369049794350982   AS  9   133320781
TBBA-KK-A7AV-01A-11D-A32C-05    g13597397   0.235754213039205   AS  9   133320948
TBBA-KK-A7AV-01A-11D-A32C-05    g13835114   0.155860360642954   AS  9   133327530
TBBA-KK-A7AV-01A-11D-A32C-05    g14010829   0.668836842295365   AS  9
[N]
 ...

Desired output:
[1]     
TBBA-06-5415-01A-01D-1481-05    g01023169   0.956810537
TBBA-06-5415-01A-01D-1481-05    g03242877   0.036583431
TBBA-06-5415-01A-01D-1481-05    g06008330   0.040030231
TBBA-06-5415-01A-01D-1481-05    g08861569   0.055629657
TBBA-06-5415-01A-01D-1481-05    g09748749   0.183017408
[2]     
TBBA-62-A472-01A-11D-A24I-05    g02726808   0.860054268
TBBA-62-A472-01A-11D-A24I-05    g04243127   0.897393495
TBBA-62-A472-01A-11D-A24I-05    g10537079   0.875143442
TBBA-62-A472-01A-11D-A24I-05    g12497728   0.935925243
TBBA-62-A472-01A-11D-A24I-05    g13195463   NA
[3]     
TBBA-KK-A7AV-01A-11D-A32C-05    g02442630   0.86283846
TBBA-KK-A7AV-01A-11D-A32C-05    g11045524   0.369049794
TBBA-KK-A7AV-01A-11D-A32C-05    g13597397   0.235754213
TBBA-KK-A7AV-01A-11D-A32C-05    g13835114   0.155860361
TBBA-KK-A7AV-01A-11D-A32C-05    g14010829   0.668836842
[N]
...
```

I am not familar with list in R. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `lapply` to loop through the `list` and extract (`[`) the first 3 columns (`1:3`).

```
lapply(lst, `[`, 1:3)
```

---

If we are reading from files into a `list`, another option is `select` option in `fread` from `data.table` where we specify the number of columns to read.

Suppose, we want to read all the `.csv` files in the working directory

```
library(data.table)
files <- list.files(pattern = ".csv")
lst1 <- lapply(files, fread, select = 1:3)
```